# Stop Firefox from asking to install flash and other plugins

Tags: firefox, flash, plugins, blocking, browser-plugin

I have absolutely zero desire for Firefox to have flash and any other 3rd party plugins installed for rendering web content.

Many times when I view web pages I get presented with obnoxious dialogs requesting me to install these 3rd party plugins. Is there any way to completely disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about other plugins but at least for Flash

Go to `about:config`

Set `notifyMissingFlash` to **False** (double-click on it to toggle)

Comment: Marking this one as accepted as I'll be using notifyMissingFlash, i might raise it to hide_infobar if other things bug me outside of flash.

Answer (score 7):

#### For Firefox v22 or less

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin` and set its value to `true`.

The [MozillaZine Knowledge base article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin) on this config settings says

> In Firefox, if media embedded in the page require a plugin that is not currently installed, an information bar is displayed at the top of the page allowing the user to install the required plugin. This preference will hide the information bar even if plugins are missing.

This sounds exactly like what you want to do...

#### For Firefox v23 or greater

The `plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin` config setting has been merged with `plugins.notifyMissingFlash`. See these bug reports on Bugzilla for more details: [869191](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=869191), [870112](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=870112).

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `plugins.notifyMissingFlash` and set its value to `false`.

Note that from what I've read this only works for the Flash player plugin.

#### Alternative Option

When you get the infobar, next to the `Install Flash` button, there should be an arrow. If you click on this there should be an option that says *Don't ask again*

[image: Firefox Missing Plugin Don't ask again]

Comment: That entry doesn't exist in more recent versions of Firefox

Comment: @justbrowsing, What makes you think it doesn't? I'm using Firefox version 22.0 and it's listed for me when I go to `about:config`...

Comment: @justbrowsing, Never mind. I figured it out. Looks like only in the very latest version (v23) they have removed it. I updated my answer.

Comment: `plugins.notifyMissingFlash` needs to be set to **false** not true. And yes **true** for `plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin`

Comment: @druciferre Great answer

Comment: @Chris Marisic, I'm kind of glad you accepted @justbrowsings answer. He posted `notifyMissingFlash` first, so I feel like he deserves the credit for that. I posted `hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin`, but he later pointed out that doesn't work in FF 23, so rather than deleting my answer I chose to improve it.